# getting Intersections and streets from map

Tags: cartography

Am new to GIS and maps , but am working on a research concerning traffic analysis and I want to get the Intersections as nodes and the connecting streets as edges , what source could I find these data as csv at ?

Comment: I feel that this question needs more details. What software are you going to use? Why do you need Data in CSV  format? CSV data for points is OK, but it's not a good format for lines. Where is your geographical area of interest? You can edit this question and add these details to help us understand your situation.

Comment: Am actually using Network analysis software so not GIS , but the nodes and edges in my network represents Intersections and streets respectively , but I don't know where/how to get these data because am not into GIS field

Comment: What Network Analysis software are you using?  If you can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with that detail as well as the geographic area in which you are interested then we may be able to start to help.